# Display inline-flex but keep full width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I have place two `div` inside an `inline-flex` `div` one of the two divs width reduces. I'm using bootstrap:

```
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="flexx">
      <div class="foo">
        ....
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-block">
            ...
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Basically, `foo` class should be inline with `col-md-10` which it does but `col-md-10` gets small instead it should still be at 100%. Am I doing it correct? I'm not strong with css/scss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I entirely understand your issue.  inline-flex items do not default to full width.  You will need to add some css for that to happen since in the css for bootstrap the flex-grow property is set to 0;

I think adding one style and a class will fix your issue, again if I understand you right.

```
// to your html
<div class="col foo">
    ....
</div>


// to your css
[class^="col"] {
   flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Check out [this pen](http://codepen.io/Mathdrquinn/pen/dXKrEB) for help

Comment: Thats it but not sure why it's not working for me. Let me check my css.

Comment: In my code I'm assuming alot, name auto-prefixing.  If you are not using a task runner you will need to write up the different browser prefixes.

Comment: Ive coping your html and css but the text "foo class" displays on top (in your pen)

Comment: Got it. Needed to compile again. I'm using rails.

Comment: Glad you got it working.  I added the text just for visualization.  
Checkout [this guide on flexbox](https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties), it might be helpful in understanding what is going on within bootstrap.